# Background image isn't working

Tags: html, css, background-image

Why don't I see my background image?

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/7WjJ5/)

**CSS**

```
.arrow_icon
{
    display: block;
    width: 320px; // 25
    height: 240px; // 25
    background-image: url(http://s12.postimg.org/yi7yl766z/5b8nbn.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.a1
{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="3">
    <tr>
        <td><span id="a2" class="arrow_icon a6" isClicked="0"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: probably should use `div` instead of `span` since it is already a block element.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP was using the wrong syntax for comments

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thank you but it doesn't work:

Comment: also http://s12.postimg.org/yi7yl766z/5b8nbn.jpg redirects to http://postimg.org/image/o85jlygbd/full/ which is a webpage not an actual image

Comment: @j08691: Why would that mean it is off-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS does not support C++-style comments.
They create syntax errors which cause the parser to skip the subsequent properties (until the next semicolon).

Remove the `//`s.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: CSS does support `/* */`, if you need comments.